# Две inline keyboards telegram

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Есть вот такой код:

```
 `
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
bot.onText(/\/curse/, (msg, match) => {
const chatId = msg.chat.id;
bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Val?", {
reply_markup: {
   inline_keyboard: [
      [
            {
                text:"USD $",
                callback_data: "USD"
            }

         ]
     ]
   }
  });
});
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
const id = query.message.chat.id;

request('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5', 
(err, res, body) => {
   const data = JSON.parse(body);
   const result = data.filter(item => item.ccy === query.data)[0];
   let md = `
   *${result.ccy} => ${result.base_ccy}*
     Buy: _${result.buy}_
     Sale: _${result.sale}_
   `;
 bot.sendMessage(id, md, {parse_mode: "Markdown"});
});
});
bot.onText(/\/rasp/, (msg, match) => {
const chatId = msg.chat.id;
bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Day?", {
  reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
            {
                text: "Mon",
                callback_data: "monday"
            }  
        ]
      ]
   }
 })
});
```

Как можно сделать эти клавиатуры уникальными или просто решить эту ошибку?
Ошибка:

```
  `*${result.ccy} => ${result.base_ccy}*
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ccy' of undefined
at Request.request [as _callback] 
(C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\smth\node\app.js:43:19)
at Request.self.callback 
(C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\smth\node\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\smth\node\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\smth\node\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)`
```

Comment: просто у тебя в результате операции `const result = data.filter(item => item.ccy === query.data)[0]` в переменной result живёт undefined

Comment: Наверное, это из-за того, что я сюда не весть код скопировал(не подключены библиотеки)

Comment: Нет, это из-за того что к условию `item.ccy === query.data` не подходит ни одна валюта. я бы в нашем месте распечатал бы в консоль и `item.ccy`, и `query.data`, посмотрел бы, поприводил к ловеркейсу и т.п.

Comment: Проблема в том, что callback_data путается и оно сравнивает день с валютой. Возможны, вы знаете как их можно уникализировать?

Comment: выложи поделку на repl.it и я попробую тебе помочь